# Grails external configuration (datasource) with multiple environments

Tags: grails, configuration, external

In my `Config.groovy` i put line:

```
grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:app-config.properties"]
```

where I set definition for datasource. File looks like:

```
dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://host/instance
dataSource.username=u
dataSource.password=p
```

and it properly replace properties from `DataSource.groovy`.

Problem is that it replace configuration for every environment, but i need separate config for dev, test and production. Trying to put into file different entries like:

```
environments.development.dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://host/dev
...
environments.production.dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://host/prod
...
```

ends with default data sources properties defined in `DataSource.groovy`. How to make one property file to work with different environments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several possible approaches.  Here are a couple:

1. Embed the current environment name in your external config file name:

   `grails.config.locations = [
   "classpath:app-${grails.util.Environment.current.name}-config.properties"]`

   This will cause `app-development-config.properties` to be loaded in dev mode, `app-test-config.properties` in test, etc.
2. Use the `.groovy` config format instead of `.properties`.  With a `.groovy` config file, you can use the `environment { ... }` block.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer bring me to this post: http://johnrellis.blogspot.com/2010/11/grails-quick-tip-external-configs.html and I used mixed solution (external file for production and native config for dev and test).